# How can I delete the rows of a table which stores foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

**THE SOLUTION IS BELOW**

I have three tables like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_arch_layer` (
  `arch_layer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `arch_layer_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`arch_layer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t_tech` (
  `tech_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tech_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tech_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tech_icon` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tech_id`),
  KEY `fk_t_tech_t_tech_type1_idx` (`tech_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_tech_t_tech_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`tech_type_id`) REFERENCES `t_tech_type` (`tech_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t_arch_layer_tech` (
  `arch_layer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tech_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tech_id`,`arch_layer_id`),
  KEY `fk_t_layer_has_t_tech_t_tech1_idx` (`tech_id`),
  KEY `fk_t_layer_has_t_tech_t_layer1_idx` (`arch_layer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_layer_has_t_tech_t_layer1` FOREIGN KEY (`arch_layer_id`) REFERENCES `t_arch_layer` (`arch_layer_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_layer_has_t_tech_t_tech1` FOREIGN KEY (`tech_id`) REFERENCES `t_tech` (`tech_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Basically it's a tipical situation where one table use two foreign keys from another two different tables. This table stores the possible combinations between the layers and technologies so it can't store any combination of layer_id and tech_id which is not in both.

But there is a problem, I need to delete whenever I want some row from `t_arch_layer_tech`. This it's impossible due to the foreign keys, I know it.

My question is, is there something to use the foreign key as a reference to forbide insert values that there aren't into `t_tech` or `t_arch_layer` and also to be consider as "own fields" (I can't explain better) of the table in order to delete any row of the `t_arch_layer_tech` table? Delete t_tech and t_arch_layer tables to avoid the foreign keys and then set the limits into the t_arch_layer_tech is not a solution.

**SOLUTION**

When that error appears it's neccesary to check the DB relationships and read carefully the provided message. It seems useless but it helped me to understand what's happening with the `t_arch_layer_tech` FK. I was using them into another table **BUT** separately, not as a compound FK. This is the reason because I could insert some rows into `t_arch_layer_tech` and delete only specific pairs.

So, summarizing, if you are going to use FKs that exist together (as my pair "arch_layer_id, tech_id") create **ONLY ONE FK** which is a compound FK that uses the mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you should have no issue deleting from `t_arch_layer_tech`; nothing references it. Now, if you want to delete from `t_arch_layer` or `t_tech` when `t_arch_layer_tech` references them, you'd have an issue.

Comment: @Uueerdo then there is something wrong because I can insert but not delete data from `t_arch_layer_tech` table. It produces the famous error code 1451

Comment: Regarding your edit. Are you saying there was another table not listed that referenced `t_arch_layer_tech`? `t_arch_layer_tech` cannot have a compound FK on `arch_layer_id` and `tech_id`, as there is no single table listed (other than itself) that has both fields to reference, and a single FK cannot reference two tables.

Comment: @Uueerdo There is another table which use the two FKs from `t_arch_layer_tech` to generate a compound FK. So it didn't work properly because both FK were as FKs into the new table separately instead into a compound FK